# Getting .this to the next function

Tags: jquery, attributes, this, contains

I'm using the Jquery attribute name filtering, to select all elements that have the words "world_map" in them. My html elements look like this : `#world_map_1`, `#world_map_2` etc...

Then I use `this.id` to insert the name within that function to call different elements starting with the prefix `world_map_1`. For example `world_map_1_panel_container`

this all works fine.

But now i'm looking for a way to get that same prefix information from the first function in a second function. Within that same function. If I use .that again it will refer to the selector from that second function, and not of the selector of the first function...

here's some code:

clicking on the element `#world_map_8` will give you the selector `#world_map_8_panel_container`

```
$('#'+'[id*="world_map"]').click(function() {
  $('#' +this.id+ '_panel_container').css('visibility','visible');

// Within this function I want to create a new function and be able to use that 
//same selector prefix so I don't have to hard code everything like I have to do 
//now. This is the second function within the previous one that's hard coded 
//at the moment: 

  $('#text_button').click(function() {
    $('#world_map_8_panel_movie_container').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do a reassigning of this:

```
var that = this;
```

and use `that` inside

```
$('#text_button').click(function() {
     var something = that.id
```

where that is the 'previous original' outer `this`

so:

```
$('#'+'[id*="world_map"]').click(function() {
      var that = this;
      $('#' +that.id+ '_panel_container').css('visibility','visible');
          $('#text_button').click(function() {
                $('#' +that.id+ '_panel_container').css('display','none');

      });
});
```

`that` remains available in the complete scope it is declared in.

Answer (score 3):

You can just store the id in a variable:

```
$('#'+'[id*="world_map"]').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $('#' +id+ '_panel_container').css('visibility','visible');
    $('#text_button').click(function() {
            $('#' +id+ '_panel_movie_container').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

The inner function will have access to the variable in the outer function.

Answer (score 1):

### Usig `this` through Javascript functions

*Your problem is similary to a general problem, let me show you several ways to solve.*

The problem is generally occured in `window.setTimeout()` calls, because the `this` is points to the `window` after the first call.

Sample code:

```
function testObj() {
  this.a = "foobar";
  this.b = function() {
    console.log(this,this.a)
    window.setTimeout(this.b,1000)
  }
  this.b();
}

new testObj();
```

Output

```
testObj   "foobar"
DOMWindow undefined
```

The after the next call, the function writes out `DOMWindow` to the console, which is wrong. It happens because the `window.setTimeout()` functions assigns a new `this` with [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).

---

#### Using variable to store `this` outside the function

If you want to keep the `this` value, you should use a variable and store here.

Sample code:

```
function testObj() {
  var $this = this;
  this.a = "foobar";
  this.b = function() {
    console.log($this,$this.a,"and this:",this)
    window.setTimeout($this.b,1000)
  }
  this.b();
}

new testObj();
```

Output:

```
testObj "foobar" "and this:" testObj
testObj "foobar" "and this:" DOMWindow
testObj "foobar" "and this:" DOMWindow
testObj "foobar" "and this:" DOMWindow
...
```

This code uses `$this` variable to store the original `this` which points to `testObj`.
Also you can see that after the first call the `this` points to the `DOMWindow`.

---

#### Using `.bind` to keep the original `this`

The window.setTimeout function applies a new `this` target to the invoked function. If you want to prevent applying new this target to the function, you should use the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function.

Sample code

```
function testObj() {
  var $this = this;
  this.a = "foobar";
  this.b = function() {
    console.log(this,this.a)
    window.setTimeout(this.b,1000)
  }.bind(this);
  this.b();
}

new testObj();
```

Output:

```
testObj "foobar"
testObj "foobar"
testObj "foobar"
testObj "foobar"
...
```

---

## In your case

You should use a variable and store the `this` or the `.id` in a local variable.

```
$('#'+'[id*="world_map"]').click(function() {

  var id = this.id;

  $('#' +id+ '_panel_container').css('visibility','visible');

  $('#text_button').click(function() {
    $('#' +id+ '_panel_container').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the selection is to be the same, then why not just save ourself from the overhead of re-querying the DOM? This is a pattern you'll see used often in large scale jQuery based applications:

```
$('#'+'[id*="world_map"]').click(function() {

  var $cache = $('#' +this.id+ '_panel_container');

  $cache.css('visibility','visible');

  $('#text_button').click(function() {
    $cache.css('display','none');
  });
});
```